# Working with the lowest next element across a few arrays, and saving a variable in a variable

Tags: python, arrays, minimum

Here's the situation (I've simplified it for this question):

I have four **sorted** arrays, `a`, `b`, `c`, & `d`. Each is filled with a list of integers between 1 and 1000. I want to cycle through them in order of the integers.

So for example, if

```
a = [3, 6, 8, 24, 633]
b = [1, 43, 877, 900]
c = [456, 522, 703]
```

I want to take from `b`, `a`, `a`, `a`, `a`, `b`, `c` and so on, in that order.

I am confused by a couple of things. First of all, is there a simpler way to find which is the minimum without a bunch complicated `if` statements.

For example, I don't want:

```
if a[i] < b[j]
     if a[i] < c[k]
          if a[i] < d[l]
               #my code, using a[i] as the minimum
          else
               #my code, using d[l] as the minimum
     else
          if c[k] < d[l]
               #my code, using c[k] as the minimum
          else
               #my code, using d[l] as the minimum
else
    if b[j] < c[k]
          if b[j] < d[l]
               #my code, using b[j] as the minimum
          else
               #my code, using d[l] as the minimum
     else
          if b[j] < d[l]
               #my code, using b[j] as the minimum
          else
               #my code, using d[l] as the minimum
```

because it's overly complicated and because the parts with `#my code...` are quite a few lines.

Is there any way I can find the minimum of the four variables and then save the variables in another variable containing the name of the first variables?

Comment: are your arrays sorted?

Comment: Yes, I'll update that

Answer (score 1):

since your lists are sorted, you could try [heapq.merge](https://docs.python.org/2/library/heapq.html#heapq.merge)

```
import heapq
for x in heapq.merge(a, b, c):
  print x
1
3
6
8
24
43
456
522
633
703
877
900
```

And for the second part of the problem

```
from string import ascii_letters
from itertools import repeat
g = (repeat(x) for x in ascii_letters)
h = (a, b, c)
for x in heapq.merge(*(zip(l, m) for l, m in zip(h, g))):
    print x
(1, 'b')
(3, 'a')
(6, 'a')
(8, 'a')
(24, 'a')
(43, 'b')
(456, 'c')
(522, 'c')
(633, 'a')
(703, 'c')
(877, 'b')
(900, 'b')
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to associate integers with source lists you can do something like:

```
a = [3, 6, 8, 24, 633]
b = [1, 43, 877, 900]
c = [456, 522, 703]

da = zip(['a']*len(a), a)
db = zip(['b']*len(b), b)
dc = zip(['c']*len(c), c)

da.extend(db)
da.extend(dc)

sorted(da, key=lambda x: x[1])
```

and get

```
[('b', 1),
 ('a', 3),
 ('a', 6),
 ('a', 8),
 ('a', 24),
 ('b', 43),
 ('c', 456),
 ('c', 522),
 ('a', 633),
 ('c', 703),
 ('b', 877),
 ('b', 900)]
```

Comment: That's really cool to know, but the problem in this case is, as the program executes, I will be adding to arrays `c` and `d`.

Comment: Because I'll need to re-perform this operation each time to add the newest values. It will be a mess